# Mocking behaviour resets after each test with PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

I'm writing unit tests using PowerMock, mocking behaviour of some util classes. Defining behaviour once for test class (by @BeforeClass annotation) causes:

- first test invocation to return mocked value
- second test invocation to return real method return value

Sample code:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( {A.class, B.class})
public class TestMockedMethods {

private static B b;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
    PowerMockito.when(A.getVal()).thenReturn("X");

    b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
    PowerMockito.when(b.getVal()).thenReturn("Y");
}

@Test
public void test1() { // PASS
    Assert.assertEquals("X", A.getVal());
    Assert.assertEquals("Y", b.getVal());
}

@Test
public void test2() { // FAIL
    Assert.assertEquals("X", A.getVal()); // actual="A"
    Assert.assertEquals("Y", b.getVal()); // actual="B"
}

}
class A {
  static String getVal() {
    return "A";
  }
}
class B {
  String getVal() {
    return "B";
  }
}
```

Any ideas why second test is failing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The method `PowerMockito.mockStatic(...)` invokes `MockCreator.mock(...)`. This method regsiters a Runnable that will be executed **after each test** :

```
MockRepository.addAfterMethodRunner(new MockitoStateCleaner());
```

This runnable cleans the **internal state of Mockito** :

```
private static class MockitoStateCleaner implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        clearMockProgress();
        clearConfiguration();
    }

    private void clearMockProgress() {
        clearThreadLocalIn(ThreadSafeMockingProgress.class);
    }

    private void clearConfiguration() {
        clearThreadLocalIn(GlobalConfiguration.class);
    }

    private void clearThreadLocalIn(Class<?> cls) {
        Whitebox.getInternalState(cls, ThreadLocal.class).set(null);
        final Class<?> clazz = ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(cls, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Whitebox.getInternalState(clazz, ThreadLocal.class).set(null);
    }
}
```

So you should execute your setUp before each test.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
    PowerMockito.when(A.getVal()).thenReturn("X");

    b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
    PowerMockito.when(b.getVal()).thenReturn("Y");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I understand that Mockito cleans the internal state of mocked objects after each test. I was just hoping not to invoke setUp() method once per test. Apparently PowerMockito.mock() acts the same.