# How to run @BeforeClass method before each @Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock, easymock

When I run my @Tests manualy, one by one - everything is fine. But when I run them all together - I`ve got an error. So how can I run @BeforeClass before each @Test. I cant use @Before becorse in my @BeforeClass I do some work in testing class constructor.

Testing class constructor:

```
public HttpUtils() {
    this.httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
}
```

Before class:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() throws IOException {
    mockStatic(HttpClients.class);
    final CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = createMock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
    when(HttpClients.createDefault()).thenReturn(closeableHttpClient);
}
```

If I run all test. On second test Ive got HttpClient not like mock, but like real object, and lately have error coz of it.

Comment: `@BeforeClass` executed once and typically used to bootstrap some resource-heavy environment like embedded database or to modify classes with the magic of Reflection API. `@Before` executed before each test to do some clean up between tests. I don't believe that in your case it's impossible to organize code to do that you want using these lifecycle.

Answer (score 4):

Use [@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) instead of `@BeforeClass` to execute **before every** test

```
@Before
public static void init() throws IOException {
```

> with @Before causes that method to be run before the Test method. The @Before methods of superclasses will be run before those of the current class.

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Method init() should not be static

Comment: @AntonKolosok remove static and use `PowerMockito.mockStatic(`  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955270/mocking-behaviour-resets-after-each-test-with-powermock

Comment: Still got real object, not mock

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute any method before each test class you should go for **@Before** annotation. By using **@BeforeClass** annotation you only call that method once in the test class.